# GoogleVoice numbers support with Clickatell & TextAnywhere

Tags: sms, clickatell

When I send sms text message to a google voice number from Clickatell or TextAnywhere, I get a failure alert (in the reports) and the message is not sent.

Anybody had experience with that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Google Voice doesn't support international SMSs, as [per their documentation](http://www.google.com/support/voice/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=117527)

Some providers, such as [BulkSMS](http://www.bulksms.com/) have had some success in getting message delivery to GV but the ability of the recipient to reply is not there.

Disclaimer: I work for BulkSMS